# strtotime() not returning proper time

Tags: php

I'm having trouble getting strtotime() to work correctly.

For starters, Here's my goal:
I'm trying to set it up that you can only create an article every 5 minutes.

To accomplish this I've got

```
    strtotime('5 minutes')<strtotime($lastcreate)
```

this code ^^ in my file.

```
   <?php
        echo '<ul><li>' . strtotime($lastcreate) . '</li>';
        echo '<li>' . strtotime("now") . '</li></ul>'; ?>
```

Outputs: 
1392203323 
1392228579

$lastcreate is stored in my database as now()

When i use this code to call it. The numbers differ by like 7 hours.

Does anybody know why it does this and/or a better way to go about doing this?

Comment: What's the timezone on your php and sql server? They probably do not match

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is what you are looking for, ways to set your timezone to match in both PHP and MySQL and the correct comparison.

PHP

`date_default_timezone_set('America/New_York');`

MySQL Query Run Before Your Query

`SET time_zone = 'US/Eastern'`

Your PHP Comparison

```
if(strtotime('now') >= strtotime($lastcreate . ' +5 minutes')){
    // its been more then 5 minutes since the last post
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try setting them as variables:

```
$five_mins = strtotime('5 minutes');
$last_create_time = strtotime($lastcreate);
```

Then, compare, print or store the variables.

```
if ($five_mins < $last_create_time) { ...
```

Comment: You probably missed the difference is 7 hours.

Comment: Maybe I'm misunderstanding what he was asking.  I was thinking that he was saying that the value should be 7 hours, but it is storing the `now` in there twice - making the difference zero instead of the 7 hours it should be.  For that, I was wondering if using `strtotime` again after `$lastcreate` updates the value.  Like if he reversed those and did `now` first, would it store `lastcreate` twice instead of `now` twice?

Answer (score 1):

Most probably the timezone set in MySQL is not the same as the one in PHP.

It would be nice if you could configure them to be the same.

What I always do is only use the application (i.e. the PHP code) to generate timestamps. So instead of using the MySQL `NOW()`, use the PHP `time()` and then insert that into the database.